# Implementing Promise Array with Try/Catch blocks within Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, promise

I'm still fairly new to Promises and Async within Typescript and I'm still trying to understand the best way to achieve asynchronous logic of defined functionality.

I wanted to write a function that contains a loop that will fire off several AJAX requests. I am a bit stumped on the best way to wait for all of the AJAX requests to finish and then return the Array. I came up with the following implementation, but I wanted to know if this way the best way to go about it. I also wanted to know if one of the AJAX requests fails and it enters the `catch` block, how is this handled? Does the Array have a `null` object for that particular iteration?

```
public async MultipleAsyncCalls(): Promise<Promise<ItemInfo>[]> {
    let resultSet = new Array<Promise<ItemInfo>>();

    for (let item of ArrayOfItems) {
        try {
            let ajaxResult = $.ajax(<JQuery.AjaxSettings>{
                url: "GetInformation" + "/" + item.Id,
                method: 'GET'
            });
            resultSet.push(Promise<ItemInfo><any>ajaxResult);
        } catch (ex) {
            this.ShowNotification("Something went wrong with the AJAX result");
        }
    }

    return resultSet;
}

public async ExampleCall(controllerConfigs: Promise<IControllerConfiguration[]>): Promise<ItemInfo[]> {
    //This first await will be complete near instantly as it is the function call completion
    //promise and not the AJAX completion.
    let promiseArray = await this.MultipleAsyncCalls();

    //Wait for all of the AJAX promises to complete.
    Promise.all(promiseArray);

    //Is it correct to assume here that all promsies of Array are done and this next loop will be near instant?
    let itemArray = new Array<ItemInfo>();
    for (let itemPromise of promiseArray) {
        itemArray.push(await itemPromise);
    }

    return itemArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `Promise.all(resultSet)` in your first function and return that.

```
public MultipleAsyncCalls(): Promise<Promise<ItemInfo>[]> {
    // don't try/catch here, use the catch handler after the then
    let resultSet = new Array<Promise<ItemInfo>>();
    for (let item of ArrayOfItems) {
            let ajaxResult = $.ajax(<JQuery.AjaxSettings>{
                url: "GetInformation" + "/" + item.Id,
                method: 'GET'
            });
            resultSet.push(Promise<ItemInfo><any>ajaxResult);
    }
    return Promise.all(resultSet);
}

public async ExampleCall(controllerConfigs: Promise<IControllerConfiguration[]>): Promise<ItemInfo[]> {
    // it's here where you should try/catch
    try{
        let promiseArray = await this.MultipleAsyncCalls();
    }catch(e){
         // handle error
    }
    //await doesn't work like that, remove that line below
    // Promise.all(promiseArray);

    // all this is unecessary, you are not doing anything new with 
    // the elements of the promiseArray 
    // let itemArray = new Array<ItemInfo>();
    // for (let itemPromise of promiseArray) {
    //    itemArray.push(await itemPromise);
    // }

    return promiseArray;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

a few observations :

There is no need to use the keyword `async` when a function doesn't contain the keyword `await`, it's useless, your function won't be `async` so don't use it in MultipleAsyncCalls

Comment: I see you pulled the Try/Catch to the `ExampleCall` function. What happens when lets say 1 of the 10 AJAX calls throws the exception. Do all 10 promises fail and I get no results?

Comment: If a single promise fails then yes it will throw an Error. To avoid that you could attach a `.catch(function(e){(/*..*/})` to ajaxResult directly.

Comment: Should the Try/Catch then be `MultipleAsyncCalls` so that one failure doesn't cause all other AJAX requests to appear as failed?

Comment: It's not going to work because you are not awaiting anywhere in `MultipleAsyncCalls ` just write `resultSet.push(ajaxResult.catch(function(e){/*handle error*/}));` in the loop, or await for each promise in MultipleAsyncCalls and use try/catch around await. I'd highly suggest you read the following page : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises and this one https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score 0):

What you may want is `Promise.all()`. You pass an array of `Promise`s to the method and it will wait until all of them have been resolved (or any one rejected). You also pass a callback with a parameter that will be populated with an array of all of the resolved data from every `Promise`.

[Link to `Promise.all()` for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).